# A homeomorphism between a compact set of $R^{n} - {0}$ and $S^{n-1}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I was doing this exercise and the answer give me the function$f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}-0$, $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$. I could prove that if $x_{k} \rightarrow a$ then $f(x_{k}) \rightarrow f(a)$ so $f$ is continuous but how i obtain a inverse $f^{-1}$ for this function? to prove that it's continuous.

Obs. The compact $X$ is defined such that for all semi-straght line with origins in 0. The semi-line is defined by $\{tv; t >0, v \neq 0, v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\}$.

Comment: In general, there will be no inverse (let alone a continuous one) if all you know about $X$ is that it is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^n.0$.

Comment: sorry, i forgot do add one more information about $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function doesn't have an inverse because it is not injective. We have $f(x) = f(\lambda x)$ for all $\lambda > 0$, so this is not the way to go.

Try checking that $\iota \colon \Bbb S^{n-1} \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^n \setminus \{0\}$ is a homeomorphism over its (compact) image. A further hint is that any conitnuous bijection with compact domain and Hausdorff image is automatically a homeomorphism.

Comment: sorry, i forgot do add one more information about $X$.